# How to keep track of the original msg.sender on Chainlink VRF fullfillRandomWords function?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chainlink, chainlink-vrf

I'm using **Chainlink VRF** to get a random number, but I need to keep track of the `msg.sender` that calls `requestRandomWords` when the `fulfillRandomWords` is fired. In other words I need the same `msg.sender` inside the `fulfillRandomWords` and in my tests it changes. How can I **achieve** that?

Answer (score 1):

After see the Chainlink docs, I ended up using a `mapping` to store the `requestId` for a specific **address**. This allowed me to keep track of the sender.

[image]

```
mapping(uint256 => address) private requestIdToRequester;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [`tx.origin`](https://docs.guardrails.io/docs/vulnerabilities/solidity/use_of_insecure_function#:%7E:text=tx.,calls%20into%20a%20malicious%20contract.) global variable to achieve what you need. However, please understand that it has security [issues](https://hackernoon.com/hacking-solidity-contracts-using-txorigin-for-authorization-are-vulnerable-to-phishing).

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip, will try it out. If you know any other way to do it, please, let me know.

Comment: just tried to use the `tx.origin` here. On `requestRandomWords` the `msg.sender` and `tx.origin` are the same, but different on `fullfillRandomWords`.